# Function that counts the number of integers in a text file?

Tags: c++, file-io

I need to write just a function that counts the number of integers in an already opened and good text file.

a. Assume there is a text file with a large number of integers divided by spaces

b. Write a function called analyzeFile that accepts a previously opened ifstream
file object as a parameter, and counts the number of integers in the file.

c. It does not need to do anything with the integers, but it must count exactly the
correct number of integers in the file and return that number to the calling
function.

d. It also does not need to manipulate the file operations themselves, so it does not
need to close the file or conduct any other actions other than counting the integers
and returning the number of them.

Thank you for any help on my problem!

**Edit:**
Here is what I have as a function do far, is it right, I don't know:

```
int analizeFile (ifstream &inf, const string &fileName) { 
   int count = 1; 
   int num; 
   fin.open(fileName.c_str() ); 
   fin >> num; 
   while (fin.good() ) { 
      fin>> num; 
      count ++; 
   } 
   return count;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code that you have written. And any problems you have faced.

Comment: Yes, please post what you have so far, and what the problem is.  Otherwise it seem like you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Here is what I have as a function do far, is it right, I don't know:

int analizeFile (ifstream &inf, const string &fileName)
{
int count = 1;
int num;
fin.open(fileName.c_str() );
fin >> num;
while (fin.good() )
  {
   fin>> num;
   count ++;
   }
return count;
}

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add that code to it? That will help others who have this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Comments:

```
int analizeFile (ifstream &inf, const string &fileName) {
```

Since the count is always a non-negative quantity, I'd prefer to use `size_t` rather than int. Nit: You may want to change the name of the function to `analyzeFile`.

```
int count = 1;
```

Problem starts here: If your file does not have any integer then you return a wrong result.

```
 int num; 
   fin.open(fileName.c_str() );
```

No need to call `open`. This would typically be called by the `ifstream` ctor.

```
   fin >> num; 
   while (fin.good() ) {
```

Again, this is not required. You can extract from the stream and test in the `while` condition -- something which is more frequently used.

```
  fin>> num; 
  count ++; 
   } 
   return count;
}
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time and trouble to educate rather than just post a solution.

Comment: Whether or not this post *educated* the OP is certainly debatable.  At this point in the OPs "curriculum," I believed that a clear, simple example would provide the most benefit.  If the OP were ready to be learning about signed vs. unsigned integer types and constructors, it would have been apparent from the OP's question.  Seeing a code snippet with the a priori knowledge of exactly what it does can be quite enlightening!

Comment: More importantly, the `fin.good()` is even wrong. Given this file content: "21", then if he initializes `count` to `0`, he will think that there are `0` numbers in the file (because `good()` returns false if the eof bit is set). On the other side if he initializes `count` to `1`, and the content is "21 ", then he will think there are two numbers since after reading 21, no eof or fail bit is set yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a functional approach too

```
// it was previously opened, so you don't need a filename. 
int analyzeFile (istream &inf) { 
   std::istream_iterator<int> b(inf), e;
   return std::distance(b, e);
}
```

If the iterator cannot read an integer, it will set the fail state on the stream and will compare equal to the end iterator. `distance` then returns the number of iteration steps it took to reach the end iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Many many years later, you could come up with a more modern solution.

You can simply use associative containers like `std__map` or `std::unordered:map` for counting. This is more ore less the standard approach.

Then there are many many new and powerful functions availbale.

Using those, you could come up with some like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>

using Counter = std::map<char, std::size_t>;

const std::string fileName{"test.txt"};

int main() {
    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream ifs{fileName}; ifs) {
        
        // Read all data 
        std::string text{std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs),{}};
        
        // Define the counters
        Counter upperCaseLettterCount{},lowerCaseLettterCount{};
        
        // Iterate over all characters in the string and count
        for (const char c : text) {
            if (std::isupper(c)) upperCaseLettterCount[c]++;
            if (std::islower(c)) lowerCaseLettterCount[c]++;
        }
        
        // Show result
        std::cout << "\nUppercase count:\n\n";
        for (const auto& [letter,count] : upperCaseLettterCount) std::cout << letter << " -> " << count << '\n';
        std::cout << "\nLowercase count:\n\n";
        for (const auto& [letter,count] : lowerCaseLettterCount) std::cout << letter << " -> " << count << '\n';
    }
    else
        // Error, file could not be opened
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Text file '" << fileName << "' could not be opened\n\n";
}
```